# Jsp page does not work with orbeon (even demo jsp page) error: Fatal error: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: jsp, orbeon

i'm trying to use jsp with orbeon, but even jsp example demo with orbeon shows an fetal error. i post the [same problem in ops-user](http://orbeon-forms-ops-users.24843.n4.nabble.com/Urgent-Jsp-page-with-orbeon-even-demo-jsp-example-dose-not-work-with-a-error-Fatal-error-Content-is--td3456708.html). Please help some one how to fix the error and run jsp with orbon.

Comment: see my answer below. If you update your question with more information, also make sure you post a comment to my answer saying you did so, so I receive a notification from Stack Overflow.

Comment: @avernet, i've update question on (http://orbeon-forms-ops-users.24843.n4.nabble.com/Urgent-Jsp-page-with-orbeon-even-demo-jsp-example-dose-not-work-with-a-error-Fatal-error-Content-is--td3456708.html#a3465135)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide more information about the issue? I just checked, and an example like [Flickr Search](http://www.orbeon.com/orbeon/xforms-jsp/flickr-search/) works fine with the latest builds. We might be able to help if you update your question with information about the version of Orbeon Forms you're using, the URL you're going to, and the error you're getting.

Comment: i've update the problem on ops-user.(http://orbeon-forms-ops-users.24843.n4.nabble.com/Urgent-Jsp-page-with-orbeon-even-demo-jsp-example-dose-not-work-with-a-error-Fatal-error-Content-is--td3456708.html#a3465135)